# Check if a controller has a @RequestHeader dynamically (in a test)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing

Using SpringBoot I managed to get the list of all controllers dynamically (in a test) using `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, but I cannot check if the controller uses the @RequestHeader("language") or not. Is there a way to retrieve this information?
I don't think it's possible from `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

Thanks.

```
public void randomApi(@PathVariable("user") String user,
                      @RequestHeader("language") String language){...}
```

Comment: You can use java reflection api to achieve it.

Comment: that info should be available via `RequestMappingInfo.getHeadersCondition()` and then `HeadersCondition.getExpressions()`

Comment: @Lino getHeadersConditions() returns en empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RequestMappingHandlerMapping` represents all controller methods, you have to get a particular controller method that you are interested from it first. The easiest way to do it is first give a name to the controller method such as `GetRandomApi` :

```java
@GetMapping(name = "GetRandomApi" , value= "/random")
public void randomApi(@PathVariable("user") String user, @RequestHeader("language") String language){

}
```

and then get the controller method by this name :

```java
HandlerMethod hm = mapping.getHandlerMethodsForMappingName("GetRandomApi").get(0);
```

*<sub>Please note `HandlerMethod` represents a controller method and I assume you only has one controller method with this name.</sub>*

To check if this controller method has a parameter which is annotated with `@RequestHeader` , you can do something likes:

```java
for( MethodParameter param : hm.getMethodParameters()){     
        RequestHeader requestHeader = param.getParameterAnnotation(RequestHeader.class);
        if(requestHeader != null) {
            System.out.println(String.format("parameter index %s is annotated with @RequestHeader with the value %s", 
            param.getParameterIndex(), 
            requestHeader.value()));
        }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks